# ¿Como ya no mandar datos Json en duro a mi API?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net

estoy tratando de mandar datos a mi API, pero ya no los quiero mandar en duro.

Así es como tengo mi método para enviar información, pero como podrán ver, así lo tengo que estar cambiando desde el JSON y estarlo ejecutando con la información nueva.

```
            using (var stockData = new RestClient(Global.stockDataUrl))
            {
                var request = new RestRequest(Global.stockDataUrl, Method.Post);
                request.AddHeader("token", token);
                request.AddHeader("access_key", accessKey);
                request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                request.AddParameter("application/json", @"[{
                                                            ""ShopNo"": ""IBX184-0"",
                                                            ""Barcode"": ""7506538906898-0"",
                                                            ""onHandQty"": 8,
                                                            ""StockDate"": ""2022-07-26 00:00:00"",
                                                            ""Cost"": {
                                                                ""UnitLandedCost"": 0,
                                                                ""UnitNetCost"": 0,
                                                                ""UnitGrossCost"": 0
                                                                },
                                                            ""Country"": ""MEXICO"",
                                                            ""Currency"": ""MXN""
                                                            }]", ParameterType.RequestBody);
                RestResponse response = stockData.Execute(request);
                Task.Delay(3000);
            }
```

Lo que hice fue crear mis modelos

```
public class StockModel
{
    public string ShopNo { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    public double onHandQty { get; set; }
    public CostList Cost { get; set; }
    public DateTime StockDate { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
}

public class CostList
{
    public double UnitLandedCost { get; set; }
    public double UnitNetCost { get; set; }
    public double UnitGrossCost { get; set; }
}
```

Y un método para recolectar los datos de mi BD con un SP, donde mi objeto lo serializo y lo coloco `request.AddParameter("application/json",)` para poder mandarlo, pero no consigo que llegue la información.

```
            using (var stockData = new RestClient(Global.stockDataUrl))
            {
                var oList = new List<StockModel>();
                var jsonStringStock = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Global.connection))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CandK_Stock", connection);
                    connection.Open();
                    cmd.Connection = connection;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            oList.Add(new StockModel()
                            {
                                ShopNo = dr["Empresa"].ToString(),
                                Barcode = dr["Articulo"].ToString().Trim(),
                                onHandQty = (double)dr["Disponible"],
                                StockDate = (DateTime)dr["FechaInv"],
                                Cost = new CostList
                                {
                                    UnitLandedCost = 0,
                                    UnitNetCost = (double)dr["CostoPromedio"],
                                    UnitGrossCost = 0
                                },
                                Country = "Mexico",
                                Currency = "MXN"
                            });

                            var jsonStringResult = jsonStringStock.Serialize(oList);
                            var request = new RestRequest(Global.stockDataUrl, Method.Post);
                            request.AddHeader("token", token);
                            request.AddHeader("access_key", accessKey);
                            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                            request.AddParameter("application/json", jsonStringResult, ParameterType.RequestBody);
                            RestResponse response = stockData.Execute(request);

                        }
                    }

                }
                Task.Delay(3000);
            }
```

Anexo foto de mi objeto serializado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algo estoy haciendo mal? o por que no puedo mandar la información ?

Comment: Seguramente porque en el response no estas mandando jsonStringResult, si no que mandas otra cosa. Por otro lado hacer una API en .net es lo más sencillo del mundo, y tú lo estás haciendo complicado. Puedes crear 2 tipos de proyecto una API tradicional y otra que es la minimal API y listo. Nada de request ni serializar json, eso lo hace automático. Además recomiendo el uso de entity frameworks por sobre procedimientos de almacenados, al principio es complejo pero los beneficios a largo plazo son mayores

Answer (score 0):

Espero y le ayude alguien, lo que estaba mandando cuando serealizaba con

- `var jsonStringStock = new JavaScriptSerializer();`
- `var jsonStringResult = jsonStringStock.Serialize(ObjectName);`

Esto me daba el resultado con minusculas, lo cual me daba error por que no eran mis mismos parametros que tenia que recibir mi API. Entonces lo que use fue:

- `var jsonStringResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oList);`
  el cual me da el mismo formato de mis modelos que declare.